# FtpWebResponse.GetResponseStream retornando um HTML

Tags: c#, ftp

Estou realizando conexão FTP, com o `FtpWebResponse` do [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). Até aqui tudo bem, estou listando os diretórios conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299039/3497987).

Quando eu simulo um servidor FTP localmente com FileZilla Server incluso no XAMPP, eu faço a listagem dos diretórios e vem um por um em cada linha do `ResponseStream`, como no exemplo:

```
config/
app/
public/
file.xml
```

Porém testei hoje em dois servidores remotos e vem um [html](/questions/tagged/html) gigantesco.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd
">
<!-- HTML listing generated by Squid 2.6.STABLE21 -->
<!-- Wed, 27 May 2015 17:42:13 GMT -->
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>
FTP Directory: ftp://user@domain.com/
</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}--></STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<PRE>
--------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
Local time is now 18:43. Server port: 21.
This is a private system - No anonymous login
IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
</PRE>
<HR noshade size="1px">
<H2>
FTP Directory: <A HREF="/">ftp://user@domain.com</A>/</H2>
<PRE>
<A HREF="etc/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/ic
ons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="etc/">etc</A>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Jan 13 20
:39
<A HREF="logs/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/i
cons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="logs/">logs</A> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . May 14
19:06
<A HREF="mail/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/i
cons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="mail/">mail</A> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Dec 16
20:53
<A HREF="public_ftp/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-st
atic/icons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="public_ftp/">public_ftp</A> . . . . . . . . .
 . . Aug  4  2014
<A HREF="public_html/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-s
tatic/icons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="public_html/">public_html</A>. . . . . . . .
 . . . May 25 17:21
<A HREF="ssl/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/ic
ons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="ssl/">ssl</A>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Aug  5  2
014
<A HREF="tmp/"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/ic
ons/anthony-dir.gif" ALT="[DIR] "></A> <A HREF="tmp/">tmp</A>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . May  5 12
:57
<A HREF="www"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/ico
ns/anthony-link.gif" ALT="[LINK]"></A> <A HREF="www">www</A>. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Sep 30  20
14         <A HREF="www;type=a"><IMG border="0" SRC="http://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-i
nternal-static/icons/anthony-text.gif" ALT="[VIEW]"></A> <A HREF="www;type=i"><IMG border="0" SRC="h
ttp://proxy.domain.local:8080/squid-internal-static/icons/anthony-box.gif" ALT="[DOWNLOAD]"
></A> -> <A HREF="public_html">public_html</A>
</PRE>
<HR noshade size="1px">
<ADDRESS>
Generated Wed, 27 May 2015 17:42:13 GMT by proxy.domain.local (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
</ADDRESS></BODY></HTML>
```

<sub>removi algumas partes pra não ficar tão grande e também algumas informações confidenciais...</sub>

Como forçar a resposta a ser apenas os diretórios e arquivos linha por linha, ou pelo menos um XML?

---

**Edit**

Inspecionei a requisição com o [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler#Q-DOTNET), e no Inspector > Raw contém o seguinte:

```
GET ftp://user:password@domain.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

<sub>**Obs.:** Não sei porque, o Fiddler está interrompendo minha requisição e o meu aplicativo não a conclui, fica parado até dar tempo excedido, só conclui quando eu fecho o Fiddler.</sub>

**Edit 2**

Testei o programa em casa e funcionou normalmente, retornando apenas a lista de diretórios. Conforme discussão nos comentários o problema provavelmente é o Proxy da empresa.

Comment: Estranho, consegue identificar do que se trata o HTML? Você usa algum *Proxy*?

Comment: Sim uso proxy, a principio o html parece ser a listagem de diretórios, postarei uma parte dele...

Comment: Esse é o problema. Adicione no teu código a linha: `ftpRequest.Proxy = null;`. =)

Comment: Coloquei, daí não conecta...

Comment: Então defina ele com um *proxy*: `ftpRequest.Proxy = "TeuProxyAqui";`.

Comment: O servidor FTP está entendendo que a solicitação foi feita por HTTP e não por FTP por isso está respondendo com um arquivo HTML com a listagem formatada dos diretórios e arquivos. Tente verificar utilizando o Finddler2 ou o Charles ou o WireShark como exatamente está sendo feita a sua requisição.

Comment: Quando não defino o _proxy_, ou defino das seguintes formas: `Request.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();` ou `Request.Proxy = new WebProxy("proxy.dominio.local", 8080);`. Ele funciona e trás o resultado como [tag:HTML]

Comment: Você não está conseguindo passar pelo Squid, uma forma de resolver esse problema seria analisar o HTML e extrair as informações que você quer. Você pode usar o [HTML Agile Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack), e selecionar os arquivos assim: `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//A/text()")`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBrancoStracini tentei usar o Fiddle mas ele não está capturando a requisição do aplicativo, apenas dos navegadores... :/

Comment: @GuilhermeBrancoStracini consegui configurar aqui, mas ele está sequestrando minha requisição não está deixando ser completada... Enfim, na aba Inspector na opção Raw contém o seguinte: `GET ftp://user:password@domain.com/ HTTP/1.1`
`Host: domain.com`
`Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive`

Comment: Use a propriedade [`KeepAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do `FtpWebRequest`. Em último caso, se não conseguir, considere *parsear* o HTML. Usando o exemplo da pergunta consegui [esse resultado](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6qTL.png).

Comment: Você pode configurar esse Squid?

Comment: Não @CiganoMorrisonMendez, o proxy é da empresa, eu não tenho acesso às configurações, rodei a aplicação em casa onde não tem proxy e funcionou normalmente. Então o problema não é na configuração da minha aplicação? Tenho que parsear como disse o @qmechanik?

Comment: Ter tem, mas não sei se vale a pena.

Comment: @qmechanik pode postar o exemplo do parser como resposta? Acho que essa será a solução mais viável... :/ Daí vou testar mais tarde.

Comment: O proxy está roteando sua requisição FTP para HTTP, esse é o problema, neste caso você terá que fazer o "parse" do HTML devolvido pelo FTP e extrair as informações. Você pode utilizar o [HTMl AgilePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) como já foi recomendado. o [CS Query](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/) ou fazer seu próprio leitor/parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto acontece porque o *proxy* realiza a solicitação através do protocolo [*HTTP*](http://techterms.com/definition/http), e não [*FTP*](http://techterms.com/definition/ftp), o *proxy*, em seguida, realizará os comandos de *FTP* necessários e retornará o resultado para você dentro de uma resposta HTTP.

*Proxies HTTP* geralmente retornam uma página *HTML* como resultado, para que o usuário possa clicar para obter os arquivos relevantes.

Uma vez que, você não tem acesso as configurações de *proxy*, uma alternativa é analisar o *HTML* e extrair as informações relevantes.

Uma forma de fazer isto em C# é usar o [**`HTML Agile Pack`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack), segue abaixo o código adaptado, [o que foi mencionado na pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299039/3497987):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
....
...

static List<string> retornarDiretoriosFTP(string URI, string usuario, string senha) {
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
    List<string> diretorios = new List<string>();
    string resposta = string.Empty;

    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse resultado = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resultado.GetResponseStream())) {
        resposta = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var documento = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    documento.LoadHtml(resposta);

    // Se a resposta conter um HTML Válido
    if (documento.ParseErrors.Count() == 0) {
        foreach (var diretorio in documento.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(x => x.Attributes["href"])) {
            diretorios.Add(diretorio.Value);
        }
    }
    // Se não, provavelmente é a listagem dos diretórios
    else {
        foreach (var diretorio in resposta) {
            diretorios.Add(diretorio.ToString());
        }
    }          
    return diretorios;
}
```

Para utilizá-lo, faça:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<string> diretorios = retornarDiretoriosFTP("Proxy", "Usuário", "Senha");
    foreach (var diretorio in diretorios) {
        Console.WriteLine(diretorio);
    }

}
```

**Nota**: É necessário referenciar o [`HTML Agile Pack`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) no projeto.

Comment: Qmechanik, eu não encontrei uma documentação desse pacote, por ele tem como verificar se o retorno é um HTML?

Comment: @KaduAmaral A documentação é escassa mesmo, mas é possível sim fazer isto, verificando se o HTML foi analisado corretamente, atualizei a resposta. Não pude testar, por isso não posso dizer se desta forma também funciona.