# Como extrair arquivo de um diretório FTP?

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou precisando extrair os arquivos que estão nas pastas do FTP. Seguindo os exemplos que estão nesses links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c/3299039#3299039

[FtpWebResponse.GetResponseStream retornando um HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66256/ftpwebresponse-getresponsestream-retornando-um-html)

[Como fazer download de arquivos do FTP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98913/como-fazer-download-de-arquivos-do-ftp)

consegui extrair o nome das pastas do FTP porém, agora preciso saber como fazer para extrair os arquivos que estão salvos nessas pastas.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Segue o código que estou usando, que pode ser encontrado em um dos links citado acima.

Obrigado.

```
    public static void BUSCADIRTESTE(string uri, string usuario, string senha)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;           

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();

            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                directories.Add(line);
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: O quer dizer "extrair"? Fazer o download? Ou descompactar?

Comment: @jbueno, quando falo extrair, me refiro a fazer o download dos arquivos que estão nas pastas do ftp.

Comment: @jbueno, consegui resolver, vou postar o código como resposta ai caso alguém precise, já tem uma base para consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
    public static void StartDownloads(out string pstrMsg, out bool pbooRetorno, string pstrUrl, string pstrLocal, string pstrUsuario, string pstrSenha)
    {
        pstrMsg = string.Empty;
        pbooRetorno = false;

        try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pstrUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // Credenciais utilizadas para conectar no servidor FTP
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pstrUsuario, pstrSenha);

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    // Cria o arquivo no local especificado
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pstrLocal))
                    {
                        string strLinhaArquivo = reader.ReadLine();

                        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strLinhaArquivo))
                        {
                            // Gravar as informações no arquivo
                            writer.Write(strLinhaArquivo);

                            // Verifica se o arquivo extraido contém linha
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((strLinhaArquivo = reader.ReadLine())))
                            {
                                // Inseri uma nova linha no arquivo
                                writer.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pbooRetorno = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pstrMsg = string.Format("Erro:\nMétodo 'StartDownloads'\nDetalhes: {0}", ex.Message);

            pbooRetorno = false;
        }
    }
```

**Obs:** o método só está retornando um arquivo por vez. Caso tenha que fazer download de todos arquivos de uma única vez, tem que ajustar o método com alterações necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o protocolo FTP não é o mais indicado para extração de arquivos. Quando um arquivo é **extraído**, o processamento feito foi de responsabilidade do **servidor**, ou seja, você deve enviar um comando para que o servidor extraia este arquivo. Neste contexto, é possível efetuar a extração utilizando **tarefas cronometradas** ou uma **linguagem de programação** que interaja com o servidor. Você pode usar o **PHP** para extração de arquivos:

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

É possível também no **ASP.NET** com a utilização de WebServices, mas claro, depende do servidor instalado.

Comment: Boa tarde Ronan Silva, no caso php não me ajudaria. porque estou utilizando c#, gostaria de uma solução que eu possa utilizar em c# mesmo. Vou continuar pesquisando alguma outra solução.